# For some reason cant deserialize object from Firebase response

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Everything looks good. Need help in finding a mistake in code. 
By the logs that is the snapshot from firebase

```
DataSnapshot
        { key = SecondGame,
                value = {background=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fantasygameapp11.appspot.com/o/background_black.jpg?alt=media&token=b3ec1477-6b52-48b4-9296-f57f63f26837, description=SecondGameDescription, tag=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fantasygameapp11.appspot.com/o/hot_icon.png?alt=media&token=65516b45-1aca-4cac-9a39-3eddefffe499, 
            title=SecondGame, type=regular} }
```

That is the model

```
data class GameUnit (val background: String, val description: String, val tag: String, val title: String,  val type: String)
```

Thats the code of the response

```
 mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            GameUnit post = dataSnapshot.getValue(GameUnit.class);
        }
```

I know it might be already asked but I need to find the issue first of all. Is it also possible the problem is that model is in Kotlin but firebase response in Java?

Error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.model.GameUnit does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:552)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:545)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:415)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:214)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:212)
    at com.adultgaming.fantasygameapp.utils.FirebaseManager$1.onDataChange(FirebaseManager.java:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?  Is there an error message?

Comment: oh yes.sorry i will add

Comment: @DougStevenson added error message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deserializer that comes with the Realtime Database (and also Cloud Firestore) Android SDKs requires that the class you pass to it look like a JavaBean type object.  This means that it must have a default no-arg constuructor, as you can tell from the error message, and also setter methods that map to each database field.

Kotlin data classes don't provide a default no-arg constructor in order to ensure that all of its fields have an initial value.  You can tell Kotlin that it's OK for **all** of the fields not to have an initial value by giving null or some other value as a default value:

```
data class GameUnit (
    var background: String = null,
    var description: String = null,
    var tag: String = null,
    var title: String = null,
    var type: String = null
)
```

For the above data class, Kotlin will generate a default no-arg constructor for the Firebase SDK to use.  It will also generate setter methods for each var.  Note that each property is `var` and provides a default null value.

If this is not what you want your data class to look like, you won't be able to use automatic deserialization.  You will have to read each value out of the snapshot, make sure they are each not null, and pass them all to the constructor that Kotlin provides.

Comment: so it is easier just create regular data java class with getters and setters?

Comment: Whatever you prefer.  Kotlin will generate an equals method that compares all the fields, while Java will not.

Comment: I am just learning kotlin. Now prefer to make sure that everything correct in java and than tranform to kotlin manually. But now I created Java class but got the same issue. Is it possible that something wrong in response?

Comment: I don't know - I can't see your code.  It sounds like you should ask a new question with the new code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: ahhh no. I have checked logs. And still dont understand what is the problem. The response after value exactly what i need which is 100% fit with Java class model. But still got an issue

Comment: I added empty constructor to the java model class and it starts working. Thank you for help. Please edit your answer with my final solution

Comment: Please add sample of the empty constructor