# Class User does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I have followed every other answer, but it doesn't seem to work for me, maybe because this is Kotlin.

> The User class referred to in the question above is the data class in the code below

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        data class User(
            var name: String = "") : Serializable

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        
        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
               
                    val userInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                    textView5.text = userInfo?.name
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        database.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57278298/ Does it answer your question?

Comment: my data class looks similar

Comment: there are other fields, but i just need only the name

Comment: I gave mine an initial value of ""