# How to get an array list of images from Cloud FireStore into imageslider

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have saved images in Firestore in form of an ArrayList of type String which has its URL. I want to get those images stored in a field "images" into an imageslider that has Slidemodel that takes ArrayList as a parameter.

The class slideModel has the following variables:

```
private String imageUrl;
private Integer imagePath;
private ScaleTypes scaleTypes;
private String title;
```

The code pasted below is iterating over documents not the fields of a particular document

```
    db.collection("userimages").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) 
                sliderDataArrayList.add(new SlideModel(document.getData().toString(), ScaleTypes.FIT));
                imageSlider.setImageList(sliderDataArrayList,ScaleTypes.FIT);
            }

        }
```

The image slider takes ArrayList as a parameter and a Scale Type.

This code in the image slider is getting the documents into the slider not the field of that document that contains the images.[Image of how the data is structured in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhzin.png)

I want to get the "field": "images" which has the ArrayList of strings containing image URLs and then store it in the sliderDataArrayList .

```
final List<SlideModel> sliderDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

PLEASE SUGGEST TO ME A BETTER WAY TO GET AROUND IT OR AN ANSWER TO THIS PROBLEM
THANK YOU!

Comment: So you need to get all URLs from all documents?

Comment: i want to get all URLs from one document into imageslider ..is there any other way to display multiple images if u can provide an article or a documentation or source from where i can implement that. i have provided an image from firestore how the images are stored

Comment: You say "from one document", which one? The one that exists at `root -> userimages -> NhVq ... SMSr`? Have stored the document id in a variable?

Comment: Yes from that document"NhVq....SMSr" and no I have not stored document Id in a variable

Comment: Is it ok for you if I provide you answer using the hardcoded document id?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry for  confusing you can just help with the problem I asked earlier to display images of a particular document with with hardcoded document Id

Comment: Is it helpful for you, to have a solution that can help you get the array of "NhVq....SMSr"  (single) document and send it to imageSlider?

Comment: Yes sir that would be really helpful thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, because an answer for getting the data within the `userimages` array that exists in the `NhVqAzmI6Cu9q8BTSMSr` document, you say that it "will be really helpful", then here you are.

Because I cannot see any class that holds a `List<String>`, I will create one for you:

```
class DocumentClass {
    public List<String> images;
}
```

Now to get the desired array, we need to create a reference that points to the `NhVqAzmI6Cu9q8BTSMSr` document:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference userImagesRef = rootRef.collection("userimages");
DocumentReference docRef = userImagesRef.document("NhVqAzmI6Cu9q8BTSMSr");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                DocumentClass documentClass = document.toObject(DocumentClass.class);
                List<String> images = documentClass.images;
                imageSlider.setImageList(images, ScaleTypes.FIT);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

For more info, please check the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Comment: This answer seems to work but throws error ' Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel '

Comment: Most likely you have defined the list to be of type `SlideModel`, which is not correct. You should define it as String, as in my above answer. Try to change it and tell me if it works.

Comment: if i change it to List<String> the imageslider.setimageList takes only List<SlideModel> as a parameter and the file imageSlider and slideModel are a read-only file downlaoded with a dependency "implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.0'"

Comment: your answer might work if there was a way to edit these read only files or an alternate that i think is to make another imageslider class/adapter which will take List<String> as a parameter . Also thanks for helping this much i will upvote this since the answer is right but cant apply it

Comment: if u still think there is a way this can work let me know or some source with imageSlider with firestore

Comment: You might consider changing imageslider to take a List<String>, or, change the array in the database to hold SlideModel objects, and not Strings as it holds now, right?

Comment: Imageslider is a read-only file so I can't change it to take a list<string> and can't tell database object to hold slidemodel objects cause it has 4 parameters

Comment: Change the array in the database to hold SlideModel object instead of Strings and then use the solution in the linked article, ok?

Comment: Or convert the List<String> that I showed you in my answer to a List<SlideModel>, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hey, ritik raj! Is there everything alright? Have you solved the issue?

Comment: I am getting the field values in log but can put it in a imageslider I am searching for an alternative to this imageslider I will definitely let you know if this works

Comment: Fair enough, keep me posted.

Comment: the new error "showImageActivity$DocumentClass does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped" Even the SlideModel class does not hold a List<String>

Comment: i have made this ' final List<SlideModel> sliderDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();' to pass this arraylist in imagesliderof type slidemodel but how do i add the documentsnapshot.toObject(SLidemodel.class) into this arraylist

Comment: i have tried using this method too [https://origin.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-dynamic-auto-image-slider-in-android-with-firebase/]  but this one getting one image from one document

Comment: hey ALex, please help me out i really dont know what to do i am uploading the whole file on this github repo please check it out [https://github.com/sahilzilka/imageslider/tree/main/mymallapp

Comment: For that error, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036439/5246885).

Comment: If you get new errors, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: The slidemodel only takes a single string as a parameter if there was a way to add each string URL one by one into slidemodel array list then I could pass that array list into setimagelist....or assign the whole images[ ] array list from firestore directly as list into the slidemodel array list then pass it to the setimageList

Comment: It did at some point so yeah thanks a lot I will be reposting this answer I hope u and other developers can help me

Comment: hey can u help me with one more thing can u tell me atleast how to log these images in form of array list

Comment: `List<String> images = documentClass.images;` is an ArrayList. So if you only want to Log them, simply pass images to a Log statement. `Log.d("TAG", images.toString());`.