# How to solve this problems? " Could not deserialize object. "

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.example.knowledgegain.User does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

or any other way of getting data from Firestore in this situation?

[show this exception.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Wrj.png)

[problem in this object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2YGx.png)

public class WalletFragment extends Fragment {

```
public WalletFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

FragmentWalletBinding binding;
FirebaseFirestore database;
User user;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentWalletBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    try {

        database.collection("User").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
        .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                try {

                    user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
                    binding.showCoinsId.setText(String.valueOf(user.getCoins()));

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("TAG", "onSuccess: ", e );
                }
            }
        });

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("TAg", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The no-argument constructor should **not** be added in the `WalletFragment`. It must be added in the `User` class. Why? Because you need to deserialize the objects that are coming from the Firestore when using the following line of code:

```
user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
```

For more information, please check my answer from the following post:

- [Error in fetching data from Firebase to RecyclerView. FATAL EXCEPTION: ... does not define a no-argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035276/error-in-fetching-data-from-firebase-to-recyclerview-fatal-exception-does/51036439#51036439)

Comment: yes, bro.. I don't add a no-argument constructor in User class.   public User() {
    }

Comment: thanks for the help.